# How to quickly do a sitewide batch replace of CAPS HTML tags into lowercase

Tags: html, batch-processing

I have a whole bunch of HTML code throughout pages on my website and they've got all the tags and their attributes in CAPS which I don't like aesthetically, and there are a bunch of other inconsistencies and poor coding. Is there a tool or macro of some kind that can convert all the tags sitewide relatively simply without manually stepping through each file?

Some of the code is also embedded in PHP pages.

Example source code:

```
<IMG SRC="file.jpg" WIDTH=100><BR><B></B>
<? echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=JAVASCRIPT></SCRIPT>"; ?>
```

Example output code:

```
<img src="file.jpg" width="100" /><br /><strong></strong>
<?php echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://tidy.sourceforge.net/ possibly?